# Strange django ORM behaviour with threading

Tags: python, django, multithreading

I have something very strange happening with queryset results that I am trying to access in a thread started within a Django project.

The issue arising is that in the **init** of the thread everything is working fine, but when I complete what should be the same actions in the run() method - they return empty. The code and the results are below.

Any ideas on how to troubleshoot this weird behaviour would be appreciated.

CODE:

```
class FinalDataCreator(threading.Thread):

    def __init__(self, final_form_entry, **kwargs):

            print "WORKS", final_form_entry.user_form_entries.all()

            self.final_form_entry = final_form_entry
            print "WORKS", self.final_form_entry.user_form_entries.all()

            self.weirdest_thing = self.final_form_entry.user_form_entries.all()

            self.jondykeman = "JonDykeman"

            super(FinalDataCreator, self).__init__(**kwargs)

        def run(self):

            print "EMPTY", self.final_form_entry.user_form_entries.all()

            print "EMPTY", self.weirdest_thing

            print "WORKS", self.jondykeman

            print "WORKS", self.final_form_entry

new_test = FinalDataCreator(final_form_entry)
new_test.start()
```

RESULTS:

```
WORKS [<ReviewCustomFormEntry: ReviewCustomFormEntry object>]
WORKS [<ReviewCustomFormEntry: ReviewCustomFormEntry object>]
EMPTY []
EMPTY []
WORKS "JonDykeman"
WORKS ReviewCustomFormEntry
```

Thanks again, JD

Answer (score 0):

If you read the docs of thread class in Python27\lib\threading.py it says...

```
If a subclass overrides the constructor, it must make sure to invoke
the base class constructor (Thread.__init__()) before doing anything
else to the thread.
```

So Change your code like

```
class FinalDataCreator(threading.Thread):

def __init__(self, final_form_entry, **kwargs):

        super(FinalDataCreator, self).__init__(**kwargs) #why you need to pass **kwargs

        print "WORKS", final_form_entry.user_form_entries.all()

        self.final_form_entry = final_form_entry
        print "WORKS", self.final_form_entry.user_form_entries.all()

        self.weirdest_thing = self.final_form_entry.user_form_entries.all()

    def run(self):

        print "EMPTY", self.final_form_entry.user_form_entries.all()

        print "EMPTY", self.weirdest_thing
```

Then run your code

Comment: Hi, I just ran the new code with the same result. Any other ideas?

Comment: Any reason for passing **kwargs to thread init method. Also can you try initialize any simple string or integer value in __init__ first then access it in run method... like in init: self.name = "jondykeman" and in run: print self.name. please let me know the results

Comment: Hi, essentially anything else that I set in the __init__ is called without issue. It seems to be only the querysets that are being wiped. I have used this approach dozens of other times without issue - this is a very strange and annoying occurrence.